# How do I minus 2 hours from a date/time field in EVERY record in a table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to offset a timezone error from PHP. All times recorded in table 'test' was ahead by two hours. What  I want is to update each record by minusing two hours from the time that is already there.

I tried:

```
UPDATE test 
   SET LastModifiedDate = SUBTIME( LastModifiedDate, '02:00:00' )
```

But this just updates all fields with the same value.

Please assist

tthanks

Comment: you don't need the where clause in that statement.

Comment: Are you sure it's not a time zone issue?

Comment: @citizen conn I know, I was trying it to see if it made a difference and it didn't. Can you help me come up with a solution?

Comment: @Mike I'm trying to edit dates already stored; changing the timezone will only affect new dates but not the dates that are there already

Comment: that's strange that should work.. what's the output of `select subtime(test.LastModifiedDate, '02:00:00');` oh and what does `LastModifiedDate` look like?

Comment: So, accept one of the solutions.

Answer (score 11):

```
update test set LastModifiedDate = LastModifiedDate - interval 2 hour;
```

Answer (score 9):

Use the [DATE_SUB() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub):

```
UPDATE test SET LastModifiedDate = DATE_SUB(LastModifiedDate, INTERVAL 2 HOUR)
```

Test it first to be certain it's doing what you want:

```
SELECT LastModifiedDate, DATE_SUB(LastModifiedDate, INTERVAL 2 HOUR) FROM test;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
update test set LastModifiedDate = adddate(LastModifiedDate, interval -2 hour);
```

this will modify all your dates to -2 hour. you can narrow down the result in "where" section of the query by targeting specific rows.